# Face Emotion Detection using Python model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, artificial-intelligence

ValueError: Kernel shape must have the same length as input, but received kernel of shape (3, 3, 1, 32) and input of shape (None, None, 48, 48, 1).

```
from keras.models import load_model
from tensorflow.keras.utils import img_to_array
from keras.preprocessing import image
import cv2
import numpy as np

face_classifier = cv2.CascadeClassifier('./haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
classifier = load_model("./Emotion_Detection.h5")

class_labels = ['Angry', 'Happy', 'Neutral', 'Sad', 'Surprise']
```

When I try to run the .py file, the value error appears for the load_model() function. how to resolve the issue?
I am not even load the model, so I can't go further

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow 2.16.1 has a bug. Please downgrade to 2.13.1:

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
pip install tensorflow==2.13.1
```